# how to make gmail confirmation for my website?

Tags: html

Anybody know how to do like this one?(refer to image)i want to make something like this(refer to image) for gmail confirmation on my website, but i don't know where to start.

[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJ9pW.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a broad question, but I'll try to provide some help to get you started.

If you are referring to how to send an email from a website in general, you need to use a script to do so. How you do this is highly dependent on how you are hosting your website. If you are using Node.js, you could take a look at [Nodemailer](https://nodemailer.com/about/). You will have to do a bit of research with respect to what you are using to host your website.

You would also need some code to generate a link for each users email.

If you are rereferring on how to style email, you can do this with standard HTML and CSS. As far as I know, there is unfortunately no good method to insert HTML source code using Gmail.